# Interpretation of SetWriteDeadline error

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am writing a websocket server in Go that broadcasts messages to clients. I use SetWriteDeadline on each send so that the broadcast loop doesn't get stuck.

My question is: how do I interpret an error from SetWriteDeadline? In particular, should I assume that there is something wrong with that particular client and unregister it? Or is it a server-side issue that happened to get triggered on this client?

After researching SetWriteDeadline, I found that the deadline is for putting the message on the TCP stack server-side, *not* for the client to receive the message. So perhaps a better way to phrase my question is this: is there a separate TCP stack for each websocket client (perhaps this is the thing that has size WriteBufferSize), or is this buffer shared between clients? In the former case it seems like I should unregister the client on a SetWriteDeadline error, but not in the latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websocket connections are independent of other websocket connections.

Websocket connections have an underlying network connection. These network connections are also independent of each other.

An error returned from SetWriteDeadline indicates a problem with that specific websocket connection or the websocket connection's underlying network connection.

Also note that [Gorilla's SetWriteDeadline](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/21ab95fa12b9bdd8fecf5fa3586aad941cc98785/conn.go#L761-L764) method never returns an error.

Comment: Ah right, I meant to say error from the subsequent call to WriteMessage. Thanks for the info, this is very helpful!